# How to dynamically set a parameter of a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I need to get dynamically some columns name on a `.map`, because I'm trying to do a reusable Material Table component, and I'm getting some trouble on it. My `.map` is getting all the values correctly, but I can't pass the `col` as a parameter to `row`, what I can do?

```
< TableBody > {
    stableSort(rows, getSorting(order, orderBy))
    .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage +
      rowsPerPage)
    .map((row) => {
      return ( <
        TableRow hover >
        {
          colunas.map((cols, index) => ( <
            TableCell > {
              row.cols
            } <
            /TableCell>
          ))
        } <
        /TableRow>
      );
    })
  } <
  /TableBody>

const cols = [{
    id: 'viagem',
    label: 'Viagem'
  },
  {
    id: 'status',
    label: 'Status'
  },
  {
    id: 'periodo',
    label: 'Período'
  },
  {
    id: 'transportador',
    label: 'Transportador'
  },
  {
    id: 'placa',
    label: 'Placa'
  },
  {
    id: 'cteciot',
    label: 'CT-e/CIOT'
  },
  {
    id: 'centro',
    label: 'Centro de custo'
  },
  {
    id: 'valor',
    label: 'Valor'
  }
];

return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <p>Página de viagens</p>
      <Grid colunas={cols}></Grid>
    </div>
```

I need to dynamically put the `cols.id` as a row parameter.

Comment: Well, where came `colunas` from and what is it? An array?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying to do? like a codesandbox. Its hard to understand the mapping you are trying to do dynamically with what is currently posted

Comment: colunas receives as props the values from cols, it's an array.